# MySQL - Join row with the next N smaller rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
id    timestamp
1      1
23     2
12     4
45     6
3      7
4      8
```

I need this result:

```
major  minor
1      2
1      4
1      6
2      4
2      6
2      7
```

I need to join each number, with the next 3 smallest numbers. Since these numbers are inserted out of order, I can't use the ids.

Because the numbers are also not in regular intervals I cannot set a specific limit to find the max number to join with.

Solutions I have:

1. I could create a temp table and use an auto increment id to do this.
2. I can do this for a single number, and write a script to iterate through the table. This is the query for it **(Going with this for now, till something better comes up)**:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT id major_id, timestamp major_timestamp FROM timestamps WHERE interval_id=7 ORDER BY timestamp DESC limit 1) timestamps_major 
   LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT id minor_id, timestamp minor_timestamp FROM timestamps WHERE timestamp < (SELECT timestamp FROM timestamps WHERE interval_id=7 ORDER BY timestamp DESC limit 1) ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 2) timestamps_minor
   ON major_timestamp>minor_timestamp
   ```

This just needs to be done for all numbers once, and then once per day to calculate and store a moving average. So speed is not an issue.

Wondering what is the best way to approach this. Thanks.

EDIT:
This is the actual table with timestamps and ids. The example I posted is just simplified for the sake of the question.

```
CREATE TABLE `timestamps` (
 `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `interval_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `interval_timestamp` (`interval_id`,`timestamp`),
 KEY `interval_id` (`interval_id`),
 KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
 CONSTRAINT `timestamps_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`interval_id`) REFERENCES `intervals` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=75157 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What have you tried so far????  SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: Like I said, I have solutions, as stated in my post. I was mapping it in my head trying to find another way. I just got some queries up, so I'll add them as well.

Comment: Why is it so hard to follow 3 simple instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution (see this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d08bd/4/0) to play around with it)

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable major inner join mytable minor
 ON minor.timestamp > major.timestamp
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable m WHERE m.timestamp < minor.timestamp and m.timestamp > major.timestamp) < 3
ORDER BY major.timestamp, minor.timestamp
```

I'm definitely not confident this is the cleanest solution (and I didn't do anything to handle "ties" for equal timestamps), but it does do what you want so it might be something to build off of at a minimum.

All I am doing is joining the tables then counting the number of rows "between" the major and minor so that I don't get too many.

Comment: This is very good! I never thought of putting a count inside the where. Took me a bit to understand the logic, but this is great. Thanks a lot.